# Extract multiple occurrences of string from dataframe column and parse into separate columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

### Scenario

I'm parsing out data from one dataframe column into multiple dataframe columns. Specifically, I want to parse out all the phone numbers from a column full of emails. After I parse out the phone numbers, I want to remove those phone numbers from the original email column.

### My Attempt

I start with a column in a dataframe, called "email", full of emails.

I am able to successfully parse out the **first** occurrence of a phone number, using regex, with the following line:

```
df['phone_num_1'] = df['email'].str.extract('(\(?\d\d\d\)?-? ?\.?\d\d\d-?\.?\d\d\d\d?)')
```

Running this line again, but with a new column name, captures the original phone number again...

I am able to remove **all** occurrences of phone numbers using the following line:

```
df['email'] = df['email'].replace('(\(?\d\d\d\)?-? ?\.?\d\d\d-?\.?\d\d\d\d?)', '', regex = True)
```

Now all the phone numbers are gone and I lost the second phone number.

### What I Need Help With

If there are two occurrences of a phone number in my original email column, how do I capture the second occurrence? Ideally, I would like for that second occurrence of a phone number to be parsed out into its own column.

In the end, I would have 3 columns: email, phone_num_1, phone_num_2

The email column will no longer have any phone numbers.

I appreciate the help in advance!

### Adding example email from dataframe

The email column might contain a cell with the following string:

> Installed new heat pump. System is up and running with no leaks. Gave
>   tenant  orientation on new heat pump. installed new aqua cal heat pump
>   Email:  example@domain.com | Phone: (123) 456-7890 pool heater is not
>   working. Please  contact resident at 234.567.8901. Vendor Paid
>   Pool/Spa Heater Equipment Pool/Spa  10088

Note the two unique phone numbers

I need each phone number extracted from that string and placed into columns of their own.

Comment: @Emma I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking for an example of an email?

Comment: Show us your dataframe with some data

Comment: I would do the following: 1) extract all emails from the column and store them to separate column named 'phone'; 2) extract all emails and store them to separate column named 'emails'; 3) extract whatever you want... 4) drop the original column

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand your intention due to lack of information about your dataframe. But, since you have a problem to capture the 2nd phone number, it may help you to figure out the regex. I made it recognize the email, phone no 1, and phone no 2.

```
data = ({"Email":["Installed new heat pump. System is up and running with no leaks. Gave tenant orientation on new heat pump. installed new aqua cal heat pump Email: example@domain.com | Phone: (123) 456-7890 pool heater is not working. Please contact resident at 234.567.8901. Vendor Paid Pool/Spa Heater Equipment Pool/Spa 10088"]})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for item in df['Email']:
    reg = re.search(r"(?P<email>\S+\@\S+)\D+(?P<ph1>\d{3}[\D]+\d{3}[\D]+\d{4})?.*(?P<ph2>\d{3}[\D]+\d{3}[\D]+\d{4})",item)
    print(list(reg.groups()))
```